# Как написать модульный тест для веб-приложения на Flask-е?

Tags: python, flask, юнит-тесты

Привет,

Пишу свое первое WEB-приложение на Python 3.4 с применением Flask-a. Опираюсь в основном на книгу "Flask Web Development" Мигеля Гринберга(ISBN: 978-1-449-37262-0) и официальную документацию по Flask.

Сейчас пытаюсь написать первые тесты с применением unittest.TestCase и есть несколько моментов которые мне непонятны:

1. В книге Мигеля на странице 76, там где у него несколько классов конфигураций. Зачем он ввел TestingConfig.TESTING, DevelopemntConfig.DEBUG ? Не увидел чтобы эти константы где-либо использовались.
2. Правильно ли понимаю, что для того чтобы послать HTTP GET/POST и др. запрос к приложению, то я должен получать тестовый клиент self.app.test_client() ?

**UPD**:

3. Если п.2 говорит, что "да", нужно получать тестовый клиент, тогда это означает что в каждом setUp()-методе я должен создавать instanse Flask-а, т.е. "app = myapplication.create_app('testing')" с последующим получением тест.клиента self.app.test_client(). Не будет ли создание app с помощью create_app() в каждом setUp()-методе замедлять работу тестов?

Возможно есть более правильные способы написания модульных тестов. Тогда прошу опытных поделиться знаниями

**UPD:**

В моем приложении использую следующий подход создания instance Flask-a: [Factories & Extensions](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/6fcc2ae3f4536e4d2651c1a00abe2306212a5bfd/docs/patterns/appfactories.rst#factories--extensions). То есть с помощью функции create_app(configName)

Comment: "не будет ли это замедлять работу тестов?" - скорость является последним, что вообще должно вас интересовать в тестировании. По-хорошему - да, всё окружение должно пересоздаваться с нуля. Модульные тесты **не** пишутся для веб-приложений, они пишутся для отдельных классов. Тесты для веб-приложений - это уровень системных тестов.

Comment: @Etki: ОК. Есть такие отдельные функции предваренные декоратором Flask.route() . Как их протестировать не послав запроса?

Comment: Я не знаю, я не питонщик |: Но в целом все одинаково - берется кусок кода, в него запихиваются те категории значений, которые должны (или, наоборот, не должны) прийти, на выходе проверяется, что вывод правильный.

Answer (score 1):

1. Строго говоря, эти «константы» могут и не проверяться в тестах — это параметры с которыми будет сконфигурировано приложение. Однако же проверка TESTING есть на странице 83.

   Режим TESTING отключит отлов ошибок при обработке запросов и этим поможет получать более корректную информацию в тестах.

   Режим DEBUG перезагружает локальный сервер разработки автоматически и предоставляет средства отладки.
2. Да. Обычно обращение идёт к self.app, указывающему на *someapp.app.test_client()*.
3. Нет. В **setUp** вы получаете клиента для тестов. Экземпляр приложения (*someapp.app*) у вас на этот момент уже создан.

Comment: Мне кажется Вы не совсем поняли суть моего вопроса в п.3. Обновил формулировку моих вопросов и добавил пояснение, как у меня создается instanse Flask-a.

Comment: Вам не требуется в тестах создавать экземпляр приложения несколько раз. Создайте его единожды, любым удобным способом. В методе setUp вы будете получать тестового клиента для уже созданного экземпляра. Это и обозначено в ответе.

Comment: То есть вынести из setUp() для каждого тест-метода в setUp() для всего TestCase-класса? Побаиваюсь того, что тест станет "хрупким"

Comment: Если в тестовом модуле вы полагаете работать с одним приложением, пожалуй есть смысл создавать экземпляр приложения на уровне модуля (прямо перед определениями тестовых классов).

Comment: По-умолчанию локальный веб-сервер Flask-а запускается с сетевым портом 5000. Надо ли перед получением тестового клиента принудительно ставить в это значение?